# Print Google+ Username

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**I want to display a "Login using Google+" button which causes the user's first/last name to be displayed elsewhere on the screen when clicked.**

In future versions I want users to have the option to login to my Chrome extension in 3 ways, Google+, Facebook and Guest. This is how it will flow:

> 1. User launches app.
> 2. The app window opens (fullscreen) and my UI will show them 3 buttons, giving them the 3 sign-in options.
> 3. On pressing either the Google+ or Facebook button I want to add them as unique users to my own database** and show them my main UI with their name written on the screen*.
> 4. The database will save user actions* which will be used by the various facets of my extension. E.g. Customisation of UI elements (e.g. colour, layout).
>
> *. Does not apply to guests.
>
> **. If the user already has data saved my extension will pull their unique customisations from the database when drawing the UI.

I haven't got as far as UI customisation, database implementation or Facebook authentication yet. But I thought it might help anyone answering if they know my broader aims.

I have already followed the instructions on this page (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) to fix my app ID and get my OAuth2 client ID. So I can run this code in my background.js:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
  // Use the token.
});
```

I am actually using an example given on StackOverflow for testing, which is working fine. Here's my entire background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {

  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    state: "fullscreen",
  });

  chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
      interactive: true
    }, function(token) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
    }
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + token);
    x.onload = function() {
      alert(x.response);
    };
    x.send();
  });
});
```

However, this only brings up the interactive authentication which requests their e-mail. Here's the relevant part of my manifest.json (client id deleted):

```
"oauth2": {
  "client_id": "[deleted]",
  "scopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
   ]   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use (and add) [profile scope](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#profile) to retrieve profile information of the authenticated user. Please note that the scope you used may have been deprecated as indicated on the referenced document.

> This is the basic login scope. This scope does the following:
>
> 1. It requests that your app be given access to the authenticated user's basic profile information.
> 2. It lets you know who the currently authenticated user is by letting you replace a Google+ user ID with "me", which represents the authenticated user, in any call to the Google+ API.
> 3. It lets your web app access over-the-air Android app installs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: well, it seems similar as my issue. thnks :p